# Are whitespace characters insignificant in JSON?

Tags: json

Are blank characters like spaces, tabs and carriage returns ignored in json strings?

For example, is `{"a":"b"}` equal to `{"a" : "b"}`?

Comment: spaces aren't technically blank characters

Comment: technically your brain should have parsed "blank" as "whitespace"

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Yes, blanks outside a double-quoted string literal are ignored in the syntax. Specifically, the `ws` production in the JSON grammar in [RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) shows:

> ```
> Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any of the six
> structural characters.
>
>    ws = *(
>              %x20 /              ; Space
>              %x09 /              ; Horizontal tab
>              %x0A /              ; Line feed or New line
>              %x0D                ; Carriage return
>          )
> ```

Comment: Thanks.  I had read the RFC but was unsure what kind of grammar denotation language this was -- specifically, what the * meant.

Comment: * = zero or more (from regular expression notation)

Comment: What about spaces embedded in numeric values:  is {"a":12} equivalent to {"a":1   2}   I interpret the definition "Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any of the six structural characters" to imply that whitespace is NOT allowed inside a numeric or date value

Comment: @aeropapa17 That’s correct, since neither 1 nor 2 is a JSON structural character.

Comment: The grammar notation used in the spec is Augmented BNF (Backus-Naur form), which is defined in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4234. There's a link to it in the JSON RFC but it's easy to miss.

Comment: The "railroad" syntax diagrams on json.org might be easier to understand if you're not used to BNF/ABNF/EBNF notation. Still a little tricksy though because you still need to spot that "whitespace" (defined right at the end of the page on json.org) can be empty.

(I would use the RFCs for anything implementation-related, just in case there are differences or version skew or anything between json.org and the actual standards docs.)

Answer (score 7):

In standard JSON, whitespace outside of string literals is ignored, as has been said.

However, since your question is tagged C#, I should note that there's at least one other case in C#/.NET where whitespace in JSON does matter.

The `DataContractJsonSerializer` uses a special `__type` property to support deserializing to the correct subclass.  This property is required to be the first property in an object, and to have no whitespace between the property name and the preceeding `{`.  See this previous thread: 
[DataContractJsonSerializer doesn't work with formatted JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824696/datacontractjsonserializer-doesnt-work-with-formatted-json/15445023?noredirect=1#comment23901691_15445023)

At least, I have tested that the no-whitespace requirement is true as of .NET 4.  Perhaps this will be changed in a future version to bring it more into line with the JSON standard?

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson!