# Differentiating matrices and and lists of lists in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, list, matrix, ambiguity

Suppose I have the matrix

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4]
 [5, 6, 7, 8]
 [9,10,11,12]]
```

and the list of lists

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
```

what JSON representations are in use that would enable differentiation of those two without ambiguity?

Answer (score 4):

Note: I think you can get more attention and a better answer if you add 'JavaScript' tag into the question.

First Matrix according to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4]
 [5, 6, 7, 8]
 [9,10,11,12]]
```

is not in valid JSON format, so I think you may have to write it as a two dimensional array like so:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [5, 6, 7, 8],
 [9,10,11,12]]
```

Since the white space of JSON are ignored ([Are whitespace characters insignificant in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150621/are-whitespace-characters-insignificant-in-json)) the code will be equivalent to [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]. Meaning when you pass an AJAX call you will get/send(whether you GET or POST) the Matrix in [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]] format. Thus Matrices in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) are represented in this list of lists.

However, if you truly want to differentiate a Matrix from other list of list in JSON you can add a object to it to specify that this list of list is special.

```
{
  "ImportantMatrix": [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
}
```

Once this JSON is returned you can use JavaScript to retrieve the Matrix. Like the example shown here:

```js
var text = '{"ImportantMatrix": [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =JSON.stringify(obj.ImportantMatrix)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>




</body>
</html>
```

Snippet taken from: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_json_parse

However this is assuming that you have full control and can change the format of what JSON you are getting.