# PHP JSON convertion

Tags: php, json, regex

I am trying to create a module for WHMCS. It accepts the format as below:

```
{"verifyConn": 1}
```

howevever my API returns:

```
{
    "verifyConn":1
}
```

For some reason it cannot work with this second format. So I want to remove all white space and convert to the format as above.

Any idea how I can do it ?

My codes in summary :

```
class Response {
private $_verifyConn;
// define private variables


// define verifyConn method - numeric status code
public function verifyConn($verifyConn) {
    $this->_verifyConn = $verifyConn;
}


// define the send method - this will send the built response object to the browser
// in json format
public function send() {
    // set response header contact type to json utf-8
    header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
    

        // set statusCode in json response
        $this->_responseData['verifyConn'] = $this->_verifyConn;


    // encode the responseData array to json response output
    echo json_encode($this->_responseData);
 }

}
$response = new Response();

$response->verifyConn(1);

$response->send();
```

Comment: Whitespace should not matter in JSON. See: [Are whitespace characters insignificant in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150621/are-whitespace-characters-insignificant-in-json) Your problem might be something else. Did you generate the JSON? How? Do you have any code?

Comment: When I echo "{"verifyConn": 1}" in strong to test  WHMCS returns successfull, however when I echo in JSON format with space it cannot success. I've added to original post summary of the codes I've used

Comment: Thanks for the code. `json_encode()` would normally encode without extra whitespace. You would have to use the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag to get the extra whitespace. See: [json_encode() in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Thank you! you made me realize that I was using Pretty view on Postman in fact this code returns without any space the problem with was credentials that I used on WHMCS side.

Comment: OK, nice that you managed to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

White spaces does not really matter when it comes to JSON.

What could be the cause:
setting the content type to json. If WHMCS is waiting for json string there is no reason to declare the json string as a json string if you know you have encoded it to json `json_encode($this->_responseData)`. WHMCS is already waiting for it. simply remove/comment out :

```
// set response header contact type to json utf-8

header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
```

Give that a go and see what response you get.

Do you perhaps have any json pretty print plugins installed on your browser ?
That could mean there is no space and your browser is simply formatting the string into a readable format